# Context menu item like WinRAR, "Add to FILENAME"

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, context-menu, winrar

I want to add a context-menu item like WinRAR added to files or folder's right click context menu by changing registry keys.

[image: 1]

In the picture,

> Add to "Screen Captures.rar"

WinRAR gets that name "Screen Captures" from the filename. I think WinRAR has a DLL that contains code, that gets this file name and adds dynamically to the context menu.

But in my case, I don't have a DLL so I have to do it manually. Is there any code or argument (like %1 %V etc.) that I can use on the registry keys?

My context menu item will be like:

> Send "FILE_OR_FOLDER_NAME_HERE" to Desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dynamic context menu item like the one WinRAR [creates](https://superuser.com/a/555653/138343) is impossible to do without additional code.

You can set the **(Default)** value for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<ProgID>\shell\mymenu` to a static string as follows:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\mymenu]
@="My Menu Entry"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\mymenu\command]
@="%SystemRoot%\\system32\\NOTEPAD.EXE %1"
```

This will display the following:

[image: 1]

If you attempt to use %1 or [other variables](https://superuser.com/questions/136838/which-special-variables-are-available-when-writing-a-shell-command-for-a-context) it just won't work since it'll be treated like a literal string and consequently *%1* itself will show up in the menu.

Comment: From what I've read on the other post you wrote and external links, I think it is impossible to use managed coding in order to write shell extensions. I only know C#, @Karan if it is possible I could do some coding. ?

Comment: You can write shell extensions in managed code, but is it [not](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx) [advisable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/22/10396079.aspx). For specific C# related queries you'll need to ask on SO instead.